# How can force to add an image to the disk cache

Tags: android, caching, universal-image-loader

I'm having troubles adding a local image to the disk cache manually. The reason is that I have a local photo and I need to upload this. But since I know the URL result, I want to cache this immediately. I'm using

```
ImageLoader.getInstance().getDiscCache().put(imageUrl, new File(tempFileURI));
```

But this doesn't work because when I use the line below, the file returns null

```
File thumb=
DiscCacheUtil.findInCache(urlThumbSize,ImageLoader.getInstance().getDiscCache());
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Actually DiscCache is not intended to be used directly. `DiscCache.put()` doesn't copy your file into disk cache. It just control cache size if it's limited cache.
You should copy image file into cache directory yourself:

```
File fileInDiscCache = discCache.get(imageUri);
// copy your file into 'fileInDiscCache' file
discCache.put(imageUri, fileInDiscCache);
```

Comment: hi, i cannot save images to disk. I search it but i can not find any tutorials. Could you please tell me how to save image with url into external memory, then use it ? Or could you please show me the way ? btw, i use uil, and i like it, thx. Regards